# How to use ReactJS.NET with multiple server-side bundles

Tags: reactjs.net

I use ReactJS.NET with my own server-side bundle that has ReactJS embeded. It is registered as shown below:

```
using React;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(My.Little.Website.ReactConfig), "Configure")]

namespace My.Little.Website
{
    public static class ReactConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
                .SetReuseJavaScriptEngines(true)
                .SetLoadBabel(false)
                .SetLoadReact(false) // react is included in the server-side bundle
                .AddScriptWithoutTransform("~/assets/react/server.bundle.js");
        }
    }
}
```

But now I want to use multiple server bundles because multiple "applications" are deployed on the same website and need to use their own configuration. So, for example, I want to use a ReactSiteConfiguration with its own settings per area. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

In the sourcecode of ReactJS.NET I see that the function `AddScriptWithoutTransform()` can be called multiple times:

```
public IReactSiteConfiguration AddScriptWithoutTransform(string filename)
{
    _scriptFilesWithoutTransform.Add(filename);
    return this;
}
```

So I could do:

```
.AddScriptWithoutTransform("~/assets/react/area1/server.bundle.js")
.AddScriptWithoutTransform("~/assets/react/area2/server.bundle.js")
```

But how can I select per area to only use the area-specific bundle?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.